# Async Function inside an Async Map not Resolving Promises

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am new to NodeJS (transitioning from C & Python) and have serious problems with nested async/await.

Below is the code snippet I have simplified. The nested async function *anAsyncFunction()* does not resolve the results and the execution leaves the *items.map* and returns the empty results.

```
async listAll(){
    try{
        let results = {}
        const items = [
            {'id': 125485, 'name': 'dog'}, 
            {'id': 128893, 'name': 'cat'}
        ]

        await items.map(async(item) => {
            let sub_results = await anAsyncFunction(item.id)
            // console.log(sub_results) ----> Promise { <pending> }
            results[item.id] = { ...item, subResults: sub_results} 
        })

        return { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify(results) }
    }catch(error) {
        return { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify({ message: error.message }) }
    }
}


listAll().then(results => console.log(results))

// OUTPUT: {{'id': 125485, 'name': 'dog', subResults: {}}, {'id': 128893, 'name': 'cat', subResults: {}}}
```

Exactly where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async listAll(){
  try{
      let results = {}
      const items = [
          {'id': 125485, 'name': 'dog'}, 
          {'id': 128893, 'name': 'cat'}
      ]
// You are facing issue here, here your map function creates array of promise, while simple await statement can not resolve those, So you need Promise.all API to resolve all promises and await till resolution
      await Promise.all(items.map(async(item) => {
          let sub_results = await anAsyncFunction(item.id)
          // console.log(sub_results) ----> Promise { <pending> }
          results[item.id] = { ...item, subResults: sub_results} 
      }))

      return { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify(results) }
  }catch(error) {
      return { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify({ message: error.message }) }
  }
}


listAll().then(results => console.log(results))
```

Comment: I cannot express how much I fell in love with you :D

Answer (score 1):

The problematic code is this part

```
  await items.map(async(item) => {
          ....
        })
```

You're trying to await an array of promises and not a **Promise**.
To fix this, you should use Promise.all like this

```
 await Promise.all(items.map(async(item) => {
         ....
       }))
```